# How is it possible to select a file in the home directory?

Tags: php, home-directory

In php how would I select a header file from a page that isn't in the home directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require_once('../header.php');
```

would include the header.php file from the parent directory. Use either relative or absolute paths for the require function.

Answer (score 2):

```
include('/path/to/the/header/file.php');
```

You can use absolute and relative paths. If you don't specify a path at all, PHP will search through its include_path setting and check each of those directories in sequence.

Comment: You (the process owner of php) would need _read_ permissions on the file, and _execute_ permissions on all the directories on the path of course. Otherwise the file cannot be accessed. It's not a sneaky way to access other peoples files:)